# How to translate "I hope I didn't embarrass you"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, mandarin

"I hope I didn't embarrass you" 怎么翻译？

是不是：”希望我没让你没脸“ ？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That phrase that you provided means, "I hope I didn't cause you to lose face." However, that is not a common saying.

To say, "I hope I didn't embarrass you" in the context of having accidentally said something inappropriate about another person would be:

希望沒有讓你難為情

Alternatively, you can say

希望沒有讓你覺得難為情

Answer (score 3):

Adding to BMak's answer, in a slightly different context its also possible to say "我希望没有让你觉得很**尴尬**“.

**尴尬**'s meaning is closer to "awkward", and could be also due the general situation and not only because of something someone have said or done.